# Not able to deserialize Avro specific record as a generic record in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

I would like to have a generic consumer with Spring Cloud Stream where I don't need to specify the schema of an Avro message at the compile-time specifically. Since schema id is included in the message, it should be possible to use the schema id to deserialize it to an object or generic record (this can be done outside Spring Cloud Stream framework easily). To do that, I tried to use the same approach that we have used to have a spring cloud stream application with a specific record. Obviously, this approach didn't work as I need to specify the record type at the time of consumption. It throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class com.example.avro.model.InputModel specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.
```

I was wondering if there is a way that I can consume a message from the topic without knowing the schema (and message type) at the compile time.

A snippet of the consumer:

```
@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
public void handleMessage(Object message) {
...
}
```

P.S: I am using `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer` for the value deserializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by setting `spring.kafka.properties.specific.avro.reader= false` in conjunction with the following method signature for the handler:

```
@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
public void handleMessage(GenericRecord record) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have seen similar situation and in my yml, specified *KafkaAvroDeserializer*

```
consumer-properties:
        key.deserializer:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
```

Then in the app,

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
    public void hand(Object payload) throws IOException {
        GenericRecord record = (GenericRecord) payload;

}
```